# EventBrite Get user orders giving Expansion_failed

Tags: api, eventbrite

I am trying to get all the tickets for a user from EventBrite API.

The first call i used was :

`https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/?token={{myToken}}

This gave me JSON Response:

```
{
-emails: [
    -{
        email: "myEmail@domain.com"
        verified: true
        primary: true
    }
]
    id: "{{someRandomId}}"
    name: "my Name"
    first_name: "me"
    last_name: "Name"
}
```

I extracted the id {{someRandomId}} and hit the endpoint to get all orders using:

` https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/{{someRandomId}}/orders/?token={{myToken}}

After taking some time i got the following response:

```
{
status_code: 500
error_description: "Could not expand event_id on one or more results"
error: "EXPANSION_FAILED"
}
```

Any idea what's wrong with the API call ?

Return Headers:

Date →Tue, 12 Aug 2014 20:53:20 GMT
P3P →CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue we are currently having in our V3 API. We hope to have this fixed soon, but in the mean time you can work around the issue by adding '&expand=orders' to the end of the Request URL as such:
https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/{{someRandomId}}/orders/?token={{myToken}}&expand=orders